# what is this template doing?

Tags: c++, templates

from https://github.com/wjakob/tbb/blob/master/include/tbb/tbb_allocator.h#L150

```
template <typename T, template<typename X> class Allocator = tbb_allocator>
class zero_allocator : public Allocator<T>
{...}
```

what I understand is that this is a definition for a new class, that inherits from the `Allocator` type visible in that translation unit .

the part that I don't get is `template<typename X> class Allocator = tbb_allocator` .

according to the tbb docs the `zero_allocator` takes 2 inputs, the type `T` and how many objects of type `T` you need to allocate . the `zero_allocator` also inheriths from the `tbb_allocator` which in turns defaults to a "standard" malloc/free behaviour if TBB is not present when linking .

I still don't think I get that syntax, especially the `template<typename X> class Allocator` part .

Can you explain this syntax and what is achieving ?

Comment: See [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter).

Comment: @G.M. so this code won't compile without c++17 support ? Can you exlain what this implies ?

Comment: This code will compile also in C++03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T, template<typename X> class Allocator =  tbb_allocator>
class zero_allocator : public Allocator<T>
{...}
```

What we have:

`template` starts declaration of a template

it is followed by the template parameter list:

`<typename T, template<typename X> class Allocator = tbb_allocator>`

The first template parameter is "some type" T
the next one is *not* a type, it is a template itself.

`template<typename X> class Allocator`

So the template class `zero_allocator` needs to get instantiated with first
parameter is any type T and with second parameter a template which itself takes on template parameter `X` must be given.

In addition, the second template parameter for `zero_allocator` can be left, in this case for `Allocator` parameter the template `tbb_allocator` is used.

Here a full compileable example:

```
template <typename Y>
class ExampleTemplate {};

// and the one which is used as the default
template <typename Y>
class tbb_allocator {};




template <typename T, template<typename X> class Allocator =  tbb_allocator>
class zero_allocator : public Allocator<T>
{
    // Lets use the type T:
    T some_var; // in our example, this will be "int some_var"

    // and here we use the Template Template thing...
    Allocator<float> some_allocator;

};

int main()
{
    zero_allocator< int, ExampleTemplate > za;
}
```

Comment: ok, but if I want a default type for a template parameter I can simply write `X = default`, what is the point of `template<typename X> class Allocator` ?

Comment: It kinda looks like something that wants to be a `Contract` but is not .